# Java application to make database dump

Tags: java, mysql

I needing to make a backup from my database in MySQL, with schema anda data.
Anyone does know how or have some tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html), built-in program by mysql for backup purpose

Comment: @ulima69 - Are you able to exec external command using Java? If so, install mysqldump (usually come with mysql), and understand what sort of options available for mysqldump